# Merged a branch into another multiple times - need to unpick them

Tags: git, github

I have merged BranchA multiple times into DestinationBranch (i.e. merged BranchA into DestinationBranch, continued working on BranchA, merged into DestinationBranch again).

I now need to unpick these.

What is the best approach?

1. Revert each merge individually?
2. Revert the first merge only?
3. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the single merge steps (and no other branches have been merged in), just reset the HEAD of DestinationBranch to the commit before the first merge. Then do the merge again, and remember to rebase your BranchA onto DestinationBranch (alternatively delete BranchA and recreate it from the HEAD of DestinationBranch).